# %2 is getting escaped in rewrite rule htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have below rewrite rule on apache httpd server.

```
RewriteRule ^/Apps/Learning\.aspx$ http://newptl.mycompany.com/MyPtl/Enter%20the%20Learning%20Zone? [QSA,NC,R=302,]
```

Rewrite seems to be working but it is skipping %2 and redirecting to the request `http://newptl.mycompany.com/MyPtl/Enter0the0Learning0Zone`?

I am not able to figure out why `%2` is missing while it is trying to redirect. I have tried with flags as `[R,NE]` too but still `%2` is missing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get away with using spaces directly:

```
RewriteRule ^/Apps/Learning.aspx$  http://newptl.mycompany.com/MyPtl/Enter\ the\ Learning\ Zone? [QSA,NC,R=302,B]
```

Comment: My Bad. Missed B flag at the end while testing. It is now working. Thanks for your help.